# azure external file absolute path

Tags: java, eclipse, azure, tomcat

We are working with Azure and have run into an issue that hopefully some of you have experience with.  I was unable to find any clear documentation on what to do in the following case.

1. We are deploying a Java application on Tomcat in Azure Web Apps.
2. Web application uses a 3rd party payment toolkit
3. 3rd party payment toolkit requires external file
4. 3rd party payment toolkit needs absolute path to the external file.

My question is:

1. Where can external files be placed in Azure environment ?
2. How can I find the absolute path to the external config file ?

There is no other way around it as the 3rd party library requires absolute path currently, as such putting the file in the CLASSPATH does not seem to work.  I need to put the external file in the Azure environment somewhere and then be able to reference it with an absolute path so that the library can find it.

I am currently deploying the project from Eclipse into Azure directly.

Please let me know if any of you have any suggestions.

Comment: Thanks evil, is there any way I can verify the path, either from the azure panel or somehow?  Or do they usually end up in the D directory ?

Comment: You could log on to Kudu for the web site, from there you should be able to verify the path. Go to htts://yourwebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net (just insert .scm directly after your website's name). You should now see the Kudu portal. Go to Debug console and select CMD or PowerShell (which ever you like). In the top part you will now see a file explorer and you should be able to find your file by navigating there.

Comment: @user6219373 As yoape said, you can verify the path via Kudu tool. Anything you want to know about Kudu is [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki).

Comment: Thanks to yoape for the kudu suggestion.  I did look and indeed the path is shown there.  I suppose this path will always stay the same ?

Comment: Also how would we verify the java runtime classpath in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java application lives in 
`d:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\ROOT\`, or something very close to that.
Use [Kudu's DebugConsole](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) to quickly find out the exact path you're deploying to:

[image]

Place the configuration file under the same path (but make sure it's not directly accessible from the web) or better yet `d:\home\site\some_directory`.

`d:\home\site` is world readable/writeable.